# Question regarding the connectedness of spanning 2-regular subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

If a 4-regular connected graph does not have one or more cut vertices then we can say it has a 2-regular spanning sub graph which is  connected, isn't it? (A spanning sub graph with one component)

There might be several 2-regular spanning subgraphs, some which are a union of disjoint cycles, but if there is no cut vertex above type of a spanning sub graph will also be present, right?

Can someone please guide me to understand this.

Thanks a lot in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A "2-regular spanning subgraph which is connected" is simply a Hamiltonian cycle, and in general when you have a reasonable-sounding condition for a Hamiltonian cycle to exist, it's probably not good enough.

[This MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/242886) gives one counter-example. (Here, a Hamiltonian cycle does not exist, because to visit every vertex, we would have to use the left and right vertices multiple times.)

The [Meredith graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meredith_graph) is an even stronger counter-example: it is not just $2$-connected but $4$-connected (the best we can hope for a $4$-regular graph) yet is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MishaLavrov in the graph in that link if we remove 2 vertices then it will be disconnected. Can't we get a good condition which will enable to decide that a connected 4 regular graph has a connected 2 regular spanning sub graph?

Comment: In general, determining if a 4-regular graph is Hamiltonian is [NP-complete](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82544567.pdf), so we won't have a good sufficient and necessary condition. Many sufficient conditions for Hamiltonian cycles don't work for sparse graphs, but it is a theorem of Tutte that, for example, a 4-connected planar graph is always Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you. Can we take a 4 regular graph as a 4 connected graph?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Not all 4-regular graphs are 4-connected, but some are.

Comment: Thanks @MishaLavrov. I have edited the question by adding a 4 regular graph. In that graph there exist 2 edge disjoint spanning subgraphs with one component. I.e. a Hamiltonian cycle. But I was trying to give a reason for the existence of a connected 2 regular spanning sub graph.

Comment: A reason for the 2 regular subgraph to be connected for this particular graph by using a property in this particular graph, such as absence of a cut vertex. Is there any such property?

Comment: Not really - there are plenty of graphs without a cut vertex for which you won't get that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. When considering the above graph the two edge disjoint 2 regular spanning sub graphsgraphs are connected ones. But how can I explain a reason for that with respect to the above graph? I mean is there a way I can explain that there will be a 2 factors with one component without drawing and showing it?

Comment: Even an explanation where we can explain how to draw it to get one component is ok,

Comment: I suspect that "drawing and showing" might be the best you can do in general. There might be some conditions that work for specific examples. (Also, the condition that *both* $2$-factors have a single component is even stronger than asking for a single connected $2$-factor.)

Comment: Ok, Thank you very very much @MishaLavrov

Answer (score 0):

Is this a good hint? If the graph $G $ is connected then because all degree of the vertices are even, $G $ has an eulérienne cycle.  If $G $ is not connected, then each component of $G $ has an eulérienne cycle.

Comment: This seems irrelevant to the question. Eulerian cycles are not $2$-regular spanning subgraphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot all! Is there any good condition which will enable to decide that a 4 regular connected graph has a 2 regular spanning sub graph?